# hover on a div to display another div and so on

Tags: html, css

I created a menu (without using ul and li element that I don't like), it display a submenu for each button, what I want is to be able to add sub-submenu, (and sub-sub-submenu...) without adding new css for each one.
This is what I have actually (simplified):

```
<div class="button"><a href="#">One button</a>
   <div class="submenu">                                //what works
      <div class="button">something</div>
      <div class="button">something</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="button"><a href="#">Another button</a>
   <div class="submenu">
      <div class="button">something</div>

      <div class="submenu">                            //what I'm trying (sub-sub)
          <div class="button">something</div>
          <div class="button">something</div>
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
.button
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
    display:block;
}
.submenu
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:200px;
}
.button:hover div
{  
    display:block;
}
```

I tried to use first-child but it didn't work, I don't want how to do...

Thanks

Comment: What is php related about this,question?

Comment: should just do this in bootstrap menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.button:hover > div {  
    display:block;
}
```

You need the `>` to target only direct children. 
Without it all children which match the last selector will be set to `display:block`.